# keybd_event is send after thread.sleep

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook

I am using keybd_event to simulate Key events in C#. In this example I am trying to send the Windows+D Kombination to return to the Desktop.
The following code is embedded in an button click function:

```
Robot.PressKey(Keys.LWin);
Robot.PressKey(Keys.D);
Thread.Sleep(50);
Robot.ReleaseKey(Keys.D);
Robot.ReleaseKey(Keys.LWin);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

---

```
public void PressKey(Keys key)
{

    keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 1, 0);
}

public void ReleaseKey(Keys key)
{
    keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 1|2, 0);
}
```

---

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

What I expect: I return to the Desktop and wait for 1 second.
What happens: After 1 second I return to the Desktop.

If I continue with more function calls after the Thread.Sleep(1000) it never returns to the Desktop.
What am I doing wrong? Thx ;)

EDIT: I also tried it with SendInput (copy pasted from http://damiproductions.darkbb.com/t504-c-sending-keys-with-the-sendinput-api), with the same Problem. I also replaced Thread.Sleep() with a Stopwatch and a Loop. My last try was starting it in a new Thread. This didn't help ether.

Comment: Never Sleep() in an event.

Comment: So, is there a better way to wait for 1 second after return to desktop? I've tried a stopwatch with a loop, but it didn't change anything for me

Comment: No, don't loop (for a long time) either. You now know the proper question, google it. Asked here hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that you are sleeping the whole process.
If you just want to DELAY a task, use an async methos in your stuff:

```
private async void _stuff()
{
Robot.PressKey(Keys.LWin);
Robot.PressKey(Keys.D);
await Task.Delay(50);
Robot.ReleaseKey(Keys.D);
Robot.ReleaseKey(Keys.LWin);
await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

and the part where you have this:

```
Robot.PressKey(Keys.LWin);
Robot.PressKey(Keys.D);
await Task.Delay(50);
Robot.ReleaseKey(Keys.D);
Robot.ReleaseKey(Keys.LWin);
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Change it to:

```
_stuff();
```

The difference with `.Sleep` is that your application can do some more stuff while waits and won't freeze the program :D

Comment: Thank you very much! This leads to other Problems, but I think I'll be able to handle them ;)